# How to navigate through menu items using NavigationUI

Tags: android, kotlin

I'm coming from flutter&react native so I've a little hard time to understand how navigation work in android.

I've `ShoppingCart fragment`, and I added this fragment to navigation graph without arrow.

I also added the cart icon to the app bar as a item menu.

In my MainActivity file I've this method(from google navigation codelab)

```
override fun onOptionsItemSelected(item: MenuItem): Boolean {
    return item.onNavDestinationSelected(findNavController(R.id.my_nav_host_fragment))
            || super.onOptionsItemSelected(item)
}
```

How can I navigate to ShoppingCart when I click the cart icon on the app bar?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to do this:

**MainActivity.kt**

```kotlin
override fun onOptionsItemSelected(item: MenuItem): Boolean {
        // Have the NavigationUI look for an action or destination matching the menu
        // item id and navigate there if found.
        // Otherwise, bubble up to the parent.
        return item.onNavDestinationSelected(findNavController(R.id.my_nav_host_fragment))
                || super.onOptionsItemSelected(item)
    }
```

also really important, you need to have the same id in your `nav_graph` and in your `main_menu.xml`

**main_menu.xml**

```xml
<item
        android:id="@+id/shopping_dest"
        android:icon="@drawable/ic_shopping_cart_white"
        android:title="@string/shopping_cart"
        app:showAsAction="ifRoom" />
```

**mobile_navigation.xml**

```xml
<fragment
        android:id="@+id/shopping_dest"
        android:name="com.example.android.codelabs.navigation.ShoppingFragment"
        android:label="@string/shopping_cart"
        tools:layout="@layout/shopping_fragment" />
```